# StatusChanged event of Geolocator not getting triggered in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

In windows 8 App I added the following line to add 'location toggle button' in permission flyout.

When I disable location, StatusChanged event of Geolocator is getting triggered. But if I enable location, StatusChanged event is not getting triggered.

How to solve this problem. Is there any workaround available?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but after update to Windows 8.1 the problem has gone. There is one advice: there must be only one instance of Geolocator in your application.